# Python help can't figure out why this function is failing to call inside the function call

Tags: python

I am geeting an **unresolved reference error** in calulate function when I try to call **search function**. don't know how to fix it. In my understanding I think python don't supprot function caling inside a class. then how to resolve it?

```
class round_robin:
  def __init__(self):
    self.arrive=0
    self.burst=0
    self.running=[]
    self.ready=[]
    self.dict={}
    self.map={}
    self.timestamp=2

    def add_data(self,process,arrival,dep):
        self.dict[process]=[arrival,dep]

    def search(self, dict, cnt):
        for key, value in sorted(self.dict.items()):
            if cnt >= value[0] and value[0] > 0:
                value[1] -= cnt
                if (value[1] > 0):
                    self.ready.append(key)

                    if key in map:
                        map[key] += cnt;
                    else:
                        map[key] = cnt
                    break
                else:
                    break


    def calculate(self):
        cnt=0
        for key,value in sorted(self.dict.items()):
            if(len(self.ready)==0):
                search(dict,cnt)
            else:
                search(dict,cnt)
```

Comment: It should be `self.search`

Comment: And fix your indentation. All the methods need to be indented inside the class.

Comment: Post the stack trace (full error message) as it contains the exact line where the error happens.

Comment: Indeed, if a function just call from `ONE` function you dont need declared an `self.` function. Just type a function inside a function `def cal(x): def alloc(some_war)`

Answer (score 0):

You  missed the `self.` before search

```py
lass round_robin:
  def __init__(self):
    self.arrive=0
    self.burst=0
    self.running=[]
    self.ready=[]
    self.dict={}
    self.map={}
    self.timestamp=2

    def add_data(self,process,arrival,dep):
        self.dict[process]=[arrival,dep]

    def search(self, dict, cnt):
        for key, value in sorted(self.dict.items()):
            if cnt >= value[0] and value[0] > 0:
                value[1] -= cnt
                if (value[1] > 0):
                    self.ready.append(key)

                    if key in map:
                        map[key] += cnt;
                    else:
                        map[key] = cnt
                    break
                else:
                    break


    def calculate(self):
        cnt=0
        for key,value in sorted(self.dict.items()):
            if(len(self.ready)==0):
                self.search(self.dict,cnt)
            else:
                self.search(self.dict,cnt)
```

On a side note `self.dict` is a class member i am not sure whether the dict that you are passing `self.search` is object property or you want to pass empty dictionary. If you  want to pass `self.dict` then it is not required to pass it in function call

Answer (score 0):

You can try `self.search`.
And your indentation is wrong at your `__init__` method.